# Setup page start in Ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I created ionic app blank,after I created templates folder and a file login.html in it.
Now I want set when start my app login.html page will show.
I try it with code:

app.js

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            })
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
  </body>
</html>
```

but it show white page when start.
How I can fix it?
Thank everyone!

Comment: You have configured states, but didn't set a default state. You also don't have a `<div ui-view></div>` to kick off the state provider

Answer (score 2):

You have configured states, but didn't set a default state. You also don't have a `<div ui-view></div>` to kick off the state provider.

If you want to have the login page as the start page, you have to configure it like so:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            // remove abstract true
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        })

    // Set default to /login
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
})
```

Then in your html let the `$stateProvider` know where the root of your view navigation is:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```